# Is there a way to combine Excel AVERAGEIF with AGGREGATE?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a col of phases (Phase 1, Phase 2, etc.) and col of percentage values for each phase. There are multiple of each phase and I want to calculate the average % for each phase.

I was using AVERAGEIF to calculate the average percentage for each Phase:

`AVERAGEIF(Table1[PHASE], "Phase 1", Table1[PERCENTAGE])`, etc.

That works fine. However, if any percentage values are `N/A` or errors, I don't want this to skew the calculations.

I read about AGGREGATE that ignores errors, but that only works with AVERAGE, not AVERAGEIF.
I also read about `AVERAGEIF(A1:A5,">=0")` and AVERAGEIFS for multiple error values, but this doesn't allow me to compare the PHASE col.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Use `FILTER()` function then only plain `AVERAGE()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Microsoft 365, try the following formula...

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(Table1[PERCENTAGE],(Table1[PHASE]="Phase 1")*(ISNUMBER(Table1[PERCENTAGE]))))
```

For earlier versions, try the following formula that needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=AVERAGE(IF(Table1[PHASE]="Phase 1",IF(ISNUMBER(Table1[PERCENTAGE]),Table1[PERCENTAGE])))
```

However, you say that the column containing the percentage values contain error values, in addition to the text value "N/A".  If the error values are the same type, let's say #DIV/0!, you can simply use the following formula instead...

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Table1[PERCENTAGE],Table1[PERCENTAGE],"<>#DIV/0!",Table1[PHASE],"Phase 1")
```

Change the error value for which to test accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples. I tried the last one on your list, but after manually checking the outcome, the calculated average is wrong. I.e., with a single cell in the % column with "N/A" just for testing, the formula (below) does not omit that cell from the average: =AVERAGEIFS(Table1[CURRENT STATE COVERAGE (%)],Table1[PHASE],"Phase 1",Table1[CURRENT STATE COVERAGE (%)],"<>N/A")